# MySQL 5.7 character_set_client stack at utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql, utf8mb4

Long story short: we have a PHP-based self-developed CMS, originally on PHP5.x and MySQL, using a healthy combination of utf8 and iso-8859-1 char-sets (don't judge, I know it's weird but it's working). On our production environment our server provider upgraded to PHP7.2 and (after a few weeks of refactoring) everything works just fine.

Parallel to this production environment I've set up (or at least I tried to) a test environment for our development, VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04, apache2.4, PHP7.2 and MySQL5.7.

in **/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini** I have:

```
default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
```

in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** I have:

```
[client]
default-character-set   = utf8


[mysqld_safe]
default-character-set   = utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set   = utf8


[mysqld]
init_connect                   = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-client-handshake = false #force encoding to uft8
character-set-server           = utf8
collation-server               = utf8_unicode_ci
```

Now, on our development server the `character_set_client=utf8mb4` and `character_set_results=utf8mb4` and I can't find a way to change it.

The problem is, that when I try to import on our development server dumps from our production server (through our CMS), or when I try to save texts with special characters like **ü** or **ä** it always cuts the word at the occurrence and saves only the rest, e.g. instead of **chüd** will save only **ch** or instead of **einträge** it saves only **eintr**.

However I can save **ü** manually in DB without a problem (don't have to use `&uuml;`)

(we have a second development server, Ubuntu 14.04, apache2.4, PHP5.6, MySQL5.7 and basically the same settings as on PHP7.2 testserver, and everything works fine)

Maybe PHP7.2 is doing the mess here, I am really out of ideas.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See "truncation" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

I wonder if having apache not set to UTF-8 messes up `<form>s`.

`init_connect                   = 'SET NAMES utf8'` sets 3 `CHARACTER_SET_%` values *if you are not connecting as "root"*.  So, change it to `utf8mb4` and do not connect as "root".

Are you sure about the encoding in the imported data?  (I suspect this causes the truncation problem.)  Can you get a hex dump of a small portion of the data.

For Western European languages, MySQL's `utf8` and `utf8mb4` work the same.  That is, the `init_connect` that you have should be adequate _if the incoming data is really UTF-8, not iso...

For reference here are hex values:

```
char latin1 utf8
ä    E4     C3A4
ü    FC     C3BC
```